# How can I spawn background process when using VSTS Shell script CI task

Tags: bash, android-emulator, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm trying to run for androidTests in CI process. I use VSTS build definition for this. Before testing I must start Android Emulator. I can use Shell script task for starting the emulator, but as I cannot start the process in background, the build flow cannot proceed to next step.
I've tried all possibilities listed below:

```
nohup $ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator @emulatorForUITests
nohup $ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator @emulatorForUITests &
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator @emulatorForUITests &
```

but the emulator is still running in foreground. Am I doing something wrong or is it VSTS security feature? How can I start the emulator in background?

UPDATE (answering questions in comments):

- Starting emulator in foreground blocks build process therefore it
  must be non-blocking (background) task. The emulator starts in
  foreground (in UI) anyway. If I start it using the same script, but
  directly from Terminal instead of VSTS, the emulator starts, tests are 
  run, everything is ok
- I use my own agent (on macOS)

UPDATE2:
build log from VSTS:

```
(...)
2017-07-14T10:11:31.8195010Z emulator: WARNING: userdata partition is resized from 550 M to 800 M
2017-07-14T10:11:31.8202870Z 
2017-07-14T10:11:31.8217150Z Hax is enabled
2017-07-14T10:11:31.8230410Z Hax ram_size 0x40000000
2017-07-14T10:11:31.8246000Z HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
2017-07-14T10:11:34.0594360Z coreaudio: Could not initialize record - Unknown Audiodevice
2017-07-14T10:11:34.0627730Z coreaudio: Could not initialize record - Unknown Audiodevice
2017-07-14T10:11:34.0649440Z audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
2017-07-14T10:11:34.0671380Z qemu-system-i386: warning: opening audio input failed
2017-07-14T10:11:34.0875870Z coreaudio: Could not initialize record - Unknown Audiodevice
2017-07-14T10:11:34.0888750Z coreaudio: Could not initialize record - Unknown Audiodevice
2017-07-14T10:11:34.0902400Z audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
2017-07-14T10:11:34.5066290Z emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
2017-07-14T10:11:34.5078580Z
```

As emulator is not a background process VSTS waits for `emulator` process to finish.

Comment: Do you want to do UI test? If so, the emulator should be run in foreground for UI interactive. On the other hand, what's the result if you run that command manually on your machine? Is it running in background?

Comment: Do you use Hosted agent?

Comment: Do you need to stop the terminal manually to run other command if you run that script from terminal directly?

Comment: no, in Terminal```$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator @emulatorForUITests &``` starts the non-blocking process and continues to next line in a script

Comment: Can you post the detail build log here?

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: What's the result if you save the nohup command as a shell script on the build agent like runem.sh and then in VSTS build use another shell script to run it like: exec ./runem.sh &

Comment: I get the same goldfish error but it doesn't seem to harm me. I turn on my sim in background with ````cd $ANDROID_HOME/tools ;  emulator -avd $theAndroidSimName & ````

Comment: that's what ```$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator @emulatorForUITests &``` does. It is still blocking other build steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the emulator in the background if you run the command with & and send the output to /dev/null. We did some trial and error and it only worked if we routed the output away, I'm guessing the bash task doesn't know it should complete otherwise.

Here's an example of the line we run to start the emulator:

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator -avd emulator &>/dev/null &
```

Comment: ```$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator -avd emulator &>/dev/null &``` does the same as ```$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator @emulator &>/dev/null &```. It does not work with VSTS builds

Comment: @anakkin maybe there's a difference in what agent we're running the jobs on? Our VSTS agent is running macOS and for us that's the version that ended up working (together with a script that waits for the emulator to start).

Comment: Good point, maybe MS has updated something in the agents. I'll check this out and come back with the results soon.

Comment: Still having this issue in Dec 2018. I wouldn't want to use exe/ windows for the android UI tests

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way and it works

1. Use this tool https://filehippo.com/download_advanced_bat_to_exe_converter/ or any other to convert a batch file to exe , put the below cmd and convert to exe which comes out as say "startavd.exe"

> start cmd /C "%ANDROID_HOME%/emulator/emulator @vstsavd -wipe-data-no-boot-anim"

2. Create a windows service by running below command in Admin cmd

> sc create startavd binPath="pathto\startavd.exe"

3. Use this tool https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/ServiceSecurityEditor/ to give start access to service accounts for startavd service
4. Now in Vsts build task add a script task that executes below command

> sc start startavd

That's it..

Even though the script fails the avd would start in the machine, then run your tests and at the end kill the avd by

5. add a script task that executes below command

> Taskkill /IM  qemu-system-x86_64.exe /F